# populating json sorted by content in node.js

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongoose

i am trying to add posts to an array of topics and give them out in json, everything works perfectly but the inheritance doesnt do what i want.

```
var topicArray = [],
    postArray = [];

// Create Topic and Post Array
topics.forEach(function(topic) {

    topicArray.push({
        "id": topic._id,
         "title": topic.title,
        "slug": topic.slug,
        "lastPost": topic.updatedAt,
        "posts": postArray
    });

    var posts = topic.posts;

    posts.forEach(function(post) {

        postArray.push({
            "id": post._id,
            "author": post.author,
            "body": post.body,
            "date": post.date,
            "edited": post.updatedAt
        });

    });
});
```

it always adds ALL posts to ALL topics, instead of adding the posts only to the parent topic. they are subdocuments in mongoose so i thought it would be logical if it worked. since it didnt work i added a "topic" key to the posts, wich i used in an if to only push the posts to the array if they are the same, like this:

```
if(topic.id == post.topic) {
    postArray.push({
        "id": post._id,
        "author": post.author,
        "body": post.body,
        "date": post.date,
        "edited": post.updatedAt
    });
}
```

but it just ended up in getting NONE of the posts at all. i found out i saved it in lowercase, so i changed it to

```
if(topic.id.toUpperCase() == post.topic) {
    postArray.push({
        "id": post._id,
        "author": post.author,
        "body": post.body,
        "date": post.date,
        "edited": post.updatedAt
    });
}
```

it ended up in having ALL of them again...this problem keeps me trying for 4 hours now, i am missing something really basic here, am i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never create a new array for a topic. So all your posts get inserted to the same array, which is assigned to all topics.

```
var topicArray = [];

// Create Topic and Post Array
topics.forEach(function(topic) {

    // create a new postArray for each topic
    var postArray = []

    topicArray.push({
        "id": topic._id,
         "title": topic.title,
        "slug": topic.slug,
        "lastPost": topic.updatedAt,
        "posts": postArray
    });

    var posts = topic.posts;

    posts.forEach(function(post) {

        postArray.push({
            "id": post._id,
            "author": post.author,
            "body": post.body,
            "date": post.date,
            "edited": post.updatedAt
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: oh god it really was that easy, i just put the vars at the wrong position? thanks alot.

Comment: @F.RickReich By moving the declaration of `postArray` inside the callback, I effectively put it inside a loop, so it gets recreated every time. It's a little more than just repositioning.

Comment: i am sorry this came over wrong, i did not intend that :/ i was actually happy you showed me this! thanks again